# Creating custom table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a javascript method and I have created a table with data, it looks like :

```
Picture    Product
PicA       ProA
PicB       ProB
PicC       ProC
```

My javaScript code is as follows:

```js
function onPopulated() {
var list = $find("ace").get_completionList();
var count = list.childNodes.length;

for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var item = list.childNodes[i]._value;           
    var name = item.product;
    var category = item.category ;
    var RecID = item.RecID;
    var pic= item.pic;
    var url = "abc.com.tr/img/p_" + RecID + "_" + pic+ "_01.jpg"
    list.childNodes[i].innerHTML = '<span id="name" >
        <table>
            <tr style="width:50px;height:55px;" >
                <td>
                <img width="50" height="50"                    
                    style="textalign:center" src="' + url + '"/>
                </td>
                <td>' + name + '</td>
            </tr>
        </table>   
      </span>';
    }

}
```

I wish to create table look like:

```
Picture    Product      Picture    Product
PicA       ProA         PicD       ProD
PicB       ProB         PicE       ProE
PicC       ProC         PicF       ProF
```

How to create it? Thanks for your answers

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: i want to get data twice for example i get item.product[i] and item.product[i+1] at the same time

Comment: Javascript does not support multiline strings like you used them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you can use ajax autocomplete? if Im true you should use  `width:500px !important;` for your completionList in ajax autocomplete. You can set the width range whatever you want. Then, you can get table-2 view